# ASP.NET Countries List and DropDownlist change language code

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I want to have a link that is like this change(en-NZ) which shows the language Im using and that page will take me to another page that has a dropdownlist of countries and their language codes from there I can select from the dropdownlist which has already selected my current language and change it for all my pages, is there any sample code that implements this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Enterprise Localization Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479334.aspx):

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.Toolkits.EnterpriseLocalization.LocalizedPage" 
            trace="false" EnableViewState="true" %>
<%@ Import namespace="Microsoft.Toolkits.EnterpriseLocalization" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">
void CountryChanged(object src, EventArgs evt)
{
   myLabel.Text = String.Format("Selected {0} with value of {1}", 
            countryDropDown.SelectedIndex, 
               countryDropDown.SelectedItem.Value);
   stateDropDown.Attributes[Settings.KeyName] = 
            countryDropDown.SelectedItem.Value;
   Reload(stateDropDown);
}   
</script>

<html>
<body>
<form runat="server">
   <asp:Label key="ApplicationTitle" runat="server" 
            EnableViewState="false" /><br>
   <asp:DropDownList id="countryDropDown" runat="server" 
      key="CountryList" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="CountryChanged" 
      AutoPostBack="true" >
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:DropDownList id="stateDropDown"  key="none" runat="server" />
   <br>
   <asp:Label id="myLabel" runat="server" /><br>
   <a href="Test.aspx">Refresh</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```